# Redirect calls to a member of a class in python

Tags: python, metaprogramming, functional-programming

I was trying to 'extend' a closed class

```
collections.defaultdict(lambda: 1)
```

by addint it 2 methods, called 'vocabulary', and 'wordcount'
apparently it's impossible to setattr method to builin types, nor can I inherit from defaultdic, so I decided to write a class and redirect calls to it to the type I want to extend.

```
class BagOfWordDoc():
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = collections.defaultdict(lambda: 1)
        for method in dir(self.data):
            if hasattr(getattr(self.data, method),'__call__') and method not in ['__class__', '__self__']:
                l = lambda *args: getattr(self.data, method)(*args)
                setattr(self, method,l)

    def vocabulary(self):
        return self.data.keys()

    def wordcount(self):
        return reduce(operator.add, self.data.values(), 0)
```

However it shows upon accessing it

```
 doc = BagOfWordDoc()
 doc[123]   = 123          # yields TypeError: values() takes no arguments (1 given)
 doc.keys()                # yields TypeError: values() takes no arguments (1 given)
 doc.xxx()                 # yields TypeError: values() takes no arguments (1 given)
```

So it'is as if every lambda was mapped to the 'values' function
And 'values' is the last element of the property list

Do you know why this happens ?
As for the initial problem, I am now thinking of rewriting my own defaultdict.

### update

Based on the suggestion made, hereis the working implementation :

```
class BagOfWordDoc():
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = collections.defaultdict(lambda: 0)

    def __getattr__(self, *args):
        return self.data.__getattribute__(*args)

    def vocabulary(self):
        return self.data.keys()

    def wordcount(self):
        return reduce(operator.add, self.data.values(), 0)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either copy from class to class, not instance to instance, or just have [`.__getattr__()`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattr__) delegate to the encapsulated object.

Comment: overriding __getattr__ seems to work. thank you.
Regarding this lambda construct, do you any idea how I can capture the state of the variable 'method' at each lambda definition instead of having them all pointing to the last value ("values") ?

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean with "cannot inherit from defaultdict"? It works for me (not a very good example, but I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish, so...):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python


from collections import defaultdict
import operator


class DD(defaultdict):

   def vocabulary(self):
        return self.keys()

    def wordcount(self):
        return reduce(operator.add, self.data.itervalues(), 0)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    dd = DD(int)

    dd[2] += 1
    print dd.vocabulary()
```